# Highlight multiple positions in VIM independant of the content of the buffer

Tags: vim

**I would like to highlight certain positions in VIM. The solution should work for empty files.**

Ideally, the command should work like this (The form is just to get the idea across):

```
set colorposition=((12,12),(14,12)), ((1,1),(1,1))
```

This command would, in this case, highlight (**line 12**, **column 12**) to (**line 14**, **column 12**), as well as the first position at (**line 1**, **column 1**).

**One possible solution I found is using the command *match*.**

It works like this:

let us say we would like to color the position in (**column 3**, **line 4**). We can use a certain *highlight* group and the command *match*:

```
highlight highlightgroup ctermbg=darkred

match highlightgroup /\%3c\%4l/
```

Multiple positions can be chained together using the operator *\|*. Highlighting position **3**,**4** and **1**,**1** would be:

```
match highlightgroup /\%3c\%4l\|\%1c\%1l/
```

The caveat is that one can only highlight positions inside the existing buffer. If one wants to highlight something at a specific position, where no text exists, the command *match* will not work.

**A related option is available since Vim 7.3. To set the color for a whole column, e.g. 80, one can use *colorcolumn*.**

The command *colorcolumn* is indifferent to the text in the buffer and works even for empty files, but it only colorizes whole columns, e.g.

```
set colorcolumn=80
```

**Edit**

To clarify what my goals are and to address what has been mentioned by Ingo in the answer section:

I work a lot with Fortran 77. Sometimes fixed form source code can become difficult to handle, if a certain number of *IF THEN*, *ELSE*, *DO*, *END DO* sections are used. I would like to introduce markings for every level, let's say beginning in the 81st column.

```
       SUBROUTINE SUB(I,J)
C THE COLORCOLUMN IS VISIBLE AT C                                 C
       C=0
       IF(I .GT. 0) THEN                                           VISUAL_MARK1
          IF(J. LT. 1) THEN                                         VISUAL_MARK2
             C=2
          END IF                                                    VISUAL_MARK2
       END IF                                                      VISUAL_MARK1
       WRITE(*,*) I,J,C
       END SUBROUTINE
```

Comment: Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the use case. Have you looked into _signs_? They are two-columns wide, and always to the left, but it would fit the markers use case quite well.

Comment: The marking to the left can already be achieved using _match_ and chaining, e.g. 
`match highlightgroup /\%3c\%4l\|\%1c\%1l/`

but I would prefer to have visual marks at the right side of the window, outside of the text area.

But thanks for the suggestion, I will look into _signs_ and how it might be used instead of _match_.

Answer (score 1):

*Why would you highlight cells where no text exists?*

Because Vim is a text editor, that's not supported. As you've found out, `:match` only highlights matching, i.e. existing text. The `'colorcolumn'` is an aid for not exceeding a certain width, and as such is visible in *all* lines. `:set virtualedit=all` allows to you address non-existing positions with the cursor, but that doesn't highlight anything. The only ugly workaround I can think of is adding actual whitespace to the buffer to match those positions (and then removing them on `:write`).